# Rails / Devise: Gracefully ask user to sign in on signed-out create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm continuing to tweak the [Rails Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) project to get the authentication behavior I want.

I want to control what is allowed and not allowed at the level of specific actions rather than for a whole controller. For example, you don't need to be signed in to view posts (`index` / `show`), but you must be signed in to access the form to submit a new post (`new`) and to get a submitted post processed (`create`).

Since I would like people to be redirected to sign-in if they're not signed-in, and I'll be using that snippet over and over again in a million places, I put this in the application controller:

```
def authcheck
    unless user_signed_in?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end
```

For new posts, this seems to work:

```
def new
    authcheck #see application controller
    @post = Post.new
end
```

But for the case where I have two tabs open and I have the first one on the new post form, but I log out on the second one, then try to submit the post on the first form, I get an error about the user being null even though it seems to me like it should have been redirected:

```
def create
    authcheck
    #when not signed in, causes error "undefined method 'posts' for nil:NilClass"
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Actually, I was getting an exception page originally but I changed `exception` to `null_session` in the application controller's `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` line.

Basically: Why isn't it redirecting to the sign-in page like it was when it was just about showing the form for a new post? And, from there, what might you suggest I should do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was labouring under a false impression. I thought that a `redirect_to` was the end of execution. But it doesn't seem to work that way - after a redirect line I could, for instance, tie up the server in an attempt to [square the circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle), even if it's not tied to spitting out a webpage.

I modified my "authcheck" to return true or false, then put everything in if blocks. The first example didn't fail the old way because it was just instantiating a new post but it didn't matter if it was actually saved or not.

Change to application controller routine:

```
def authcheck
    unless user_signed_in?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
        return false
    end
    return true
end
```

Changes to Posts controller routines:

```
def new
    if authcheck #see application controller
        @post = Post.new
    end
end

def create
    if authcheck
        @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
        if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

I suspect I'm not really doing things the accepted way, so I'll hold out a few days before accepting my own answer. :-)